# -webkit-filter and transition makes video element flimmer in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html5-video, css-transitions, css-filters

I'm using CSS filters (-webkit-filter) with transition to change the brightness and opacity of some SVG icons when hovering over them. It works just as expected on the icons, but it also makes a video element on the page flimmer during the transition. If I remove the transition, the video doesn't flimmer. Here's the relevant bits of code:

HTML:

```
<div class="icon"></div>
<video src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

CSS:

```
.icon {
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg") no-repeat center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-size: 50px;
}

.icon:hover {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(.5);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

To see the problem in action, hover over the icon in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zph5La8q/), and notice how the video element gets a bit darker for a brief moment.

The problem only seems to occur in Google Chrome (I'm on version: 51.0.2704.106, 64-bit, **update:** same result in version: 52.0.2743.116).

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Chrome? Is there another way to create a similar behavior for the icon (without affecting the video)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I was setting the `opacity` property rather than `filter`. I fixed it by adding `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the element which had its opacity changed.